# JS behavior differs depending on page tree

Tags: jquery, javascript

I'm a developer for a very large real estate plugin and I'm having a lot of trouble with one of our agent sites:

The init methods used to initialize ajax functionality are called using a `jQuery(document).ready()` handler. However, this doesn't always fire, and it seems to be less dependent on the page contents than the location in the sitemap.

The theme script also uses the same jQuery ready script to run methods, and that works on all pages. This file is included in the header. My file is included in the footer, that jQuery ready script does not load on certain pages.

The site is http://mportlandrealestate.com/. The scripts seem to load on every page but those underneath the Areas and Neighborhoods top level page. Also, Areas and Neighborhoods -> Inner NE and its subpages DO work, but all others do not. If I move a page from the Inner SE tree to be a child of Inner NE it begins to work, with no content changes.

You can tell the scripts are loading through some console.group statements output in the javascript console: lightbox::init, clipboards::init, and ajax::init should all be present if the footer scripts are initializing.

Any ideas? This is baffling me.

Comment: Some added clarification: this physical script file loads on every page, its the init methods called in the document ready wrapper that do not. I can manually invoke the init methods in the browser console on pages where they do not automatically fire.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by including the JS files in the header, so there's an error in another plugin's JS that's causing the issue.